# set background color and set image over background in ImageButton - Android

Tags: android, background-image, transparency, imagebutton

I need to set a background color and an image over that background, how can i do it? Is necesary the image to have transparency? I need to control states too: pressed, focused.

Any help will be grateful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Create an ImageView (Use a transparent .PNG for your src image):**

*res/layout/yourlayout.xml*

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width=:"wrap_content"
    android:layout_height=:"wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/colorstates"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

*res/drawable/colorstates.xml*

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/regular"
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/pressed"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/regular" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes the image needs a transparent background, otherwise it will cover the background color. Use the `background` attribute for the color and `src` for the image. Also check out the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html). For the pressed state, use google!